# Code working when using integer but not absolute value

Tags: python

Here is the error where the input for 'costofkeg' is an absolute value, the traceback reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zico\Desktop\GrossSP.py", line 23, in <module>
    portioncost = (costofkeg/(kegsize/(portionsize*0.568)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

However when I change the line starting 'costofkeg' to:

```
costofkeg = input('Please enter the cost of keg. GBP: ')
```

the code will work flawlessly.

Below is the code that needs to be changed but I just don't know what to change.

```
kegsize = int(input('Please enter keg size. Litres: '))

costofkeg = input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: ')

abv = input('Please enter Alcohol by Volume. %: ')

gp = int(input('Please enter Gross Profit Percentage. %: '))

print('These are the Portion Size options (imperial measurements), 1/3, 1/2, 2/3, 1.')
portionsize = eval(input('Please choose Portion Size: '))
print ('')
if portionsize not in ['1/3' , '1/2' , '2/3' , '1']:
    print('Thank you, find your inputs below\n')


print ('Keg Size', kegsize, 'Litres')
print ('Cost of Keg', costofkeg, 'GBP')
print ('Alcohol by Volume', abv, '%')
print ('Gross profit percentage', gp, '%\n')


portioncost = (costofkeg/(kegsize/(portionsize*0.568)))
pc = format(portioncost, '.2f')
print('Portion Cost', pc, 'GBP')

netsp = 100*(portioncost/(100-gp))
nsp = format(netsp, '.2f')
print ('Net Selling Price', nsp, 'GBP')

grosssp = (netsp*1.2)
gsp = format(grosssp, '.2f')
print ('Gross Selling Price', gsp, 'GBP')
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the correct and what is the wrong version of the line starting 'costofkeg'?

Comment: There is no correct version. This is because when I try to use an integer the code will work, but only to a certain extent, I say this as when I try anything else that is not a whole number I will get the traceback shown above. What I would like is for the code to work regardless of whether the number input is an integer or a number with a decimal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let the code work with both integers and absolute values apply these changes to code.

```
kegsize = int(input('Please enter keg size. Litres: '))

costofkeg = float(input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: '))

abv = input('Please enter Alcohol by Volume. %: ')

gp = int(input('Please enter Gross Profit Percentage. %: '))

print('These are the Portion Size options (imperial measurements), 1/3, 1/2,     2/3, 1.')
portionsize = eval(input('Please choose Portion Size: '))
print ('')
if portionsize not in ['1/3' , '1/2' , '2/3' , '1']:
    print('Thank you, find your inputs below\n')


print ('Keg Size', kegsize, 'Litres')
print ('Cost of Keg', costofkeg, 'GBP')
print ('Alcohol by Volume', abv, '%')
print ('Gross profit percentage', gp, '%\n')
```

Notice the float in front of '(portionsize' this is because you can't divide strings so I had to float the variable.

```
portioncost = (costofkeg/(kegsize/float(portionsize*0.568)))
pc = format(portioncost, '.2f')
print('Portion Cost', pc, 'GBP')

netsp = 100*(portioncost/(100-gp))
nsp = format(netsp, '.2f')
print ('Net Selling Price', nsp, 'GBP')

grosssp = (netsp*1.2)
gsp = format(grosssp, '.2f')
print ('Gross Selling Price', gsp, 'GBP')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is raised since you want to do a division with a string which is not supported (as the traceback told you).

So the line to consider is the following:

```
portioncost = (costofkeg/(kegsize/(portionsize*0.568)))
```

If you take a look at the variables' definitions, you'll see that the first variable not being a number (an `int` or a `float`) is `costofkeg`.

So you should cast the user's input into a suitable datatype. Since this is a price obviously I would suggest using a `float` for this. So change

```
costofkeg = input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: ')
```

into something like

```
costofkeg = float(input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: '))
```

Additionally, you should consider catching errors when converting the datatypes. So what might happen if the user enters a text string as a price and you pass this to `float()`? In order to take this into account I would suggest using [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) blocks to handle the errors. If you tidy up your code using several function for each input you can call those functions from themselves if an error while converting the input to the desired datatype occurs.

This would look like this (just a short sample snippet using the code you already had):

```
def ask_int(string):
    try:
        val = int(input(string))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Invalid format. Your input was not an integer.')
        ask_int(string)
    else:
        return val

def ask_float(string):
    try:
        val = float(input(string))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Invalid format. Your input was not a float')
        ask_int(string)
    else:
        return val

kegsize = ask_int('Please enter keg size. Litres: ')
costofkeg = ask_float('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: ')
abv = ask_float('Please enter Alcohol by Volume. %: ')
gp = ask_int('Please enter Gross Profit Percentage. %: ')
```

The input of `portionsize` might become another problem. Writing this as a function could look like this:

```
def ask_portionsize(string):
    val = ask_float(string)
    if val not in [1/3 , 1/2 , 2/3 , 1]:
        print('Thank you, find your inputs below\n')
    else:
        try:
            val = float(val)
        except ValueError as e:
            ask_portionsize()
        else:
            return val

portionsize = ask_portionsize('Please choose Portion Size: ')
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. Please see my answer below too. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having an issue understanding what you are asking, so I will write this in general terms.

If you are going to evaluate an expression with **at least one number (float or int)**, everything must be a number.

So

```
test = input("Enter a number")
print(test/10)
```

will throw an error because `test` is a string.

To cast things to a number data type, you can do:

```
testNum = input("Enter a number that will be converted to a string")
testNum = eval(testNum)
```

or

```
testNum = float(input("Input a monetary value"))
```

To some this up, **if one item in an expr is a float or a string, they all must be floats or strings.  Check to make sure each value is a number data type.  Also, you can't divide strings!**

So just surround,

```
costofkeg = input('Please enter cost of keg. GBP: ')
```

with `float()`

Comment: So how would I change the variable of 'portionsize' into a string in this line, please.

    portioncost = (costofkeg/(kegsize/(portionsize*0.568)))

Comment: Why would you want to change it into a string? You can't divide strings. You would do it by `str(portionsize)`